# Retrive an Array from JSON using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

```
$data_array = [
                ["","","","2",""],
                ["","1","","",""]
               ];
    $myJSONString = json_encode($data_array);
    $my = [
      "id"=> "1",
      "name" => "easy",
      "data" => $myJSONString,
     ];

  $myJSON_File->add($my);
```

I want to store a matrix in JSON and then retrieve it to send it later to a javascript function. I tried but when I send it to JS function, the matrix is sent as a string. I also tried decoding it `$myArray = json_decode($output);` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way of "sending" it as a string is correct, you simply have to parse the string to get a javscript object / array to work with like this.

Use json_encode to get a string in the php file.

```js
let string_example = '{"someVariable":"123"}'; //the string you retrieve from php
console.log(string_example);
let retrieved_obj = JSON.parse(string_example);
console.log(retrieved_obj.someVariable);
```